# QtChart get axis range

Tags: qt, qtcharts

I could set the current axis range in a QtChart via:

```
chart()->axisX()->setRange(min,max);
```

What is the equivalent to get the current axis range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QAbstractAxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractaxis.html) only have a setter but all his children have access functions.

Example : `QLogValueAxis::min();`  `QLogValueAxis::max();`